# Copy selected files in bash

Tags: bash, copy, selected, xargs, cp

I'm trying to copy specific files between directories. So I listed all files with `ls`, added a line number with `cat -n` and then selected first 100 files I want to copy with `head -100`. After that I used `xargs` command but it does not work. Here is the code:

```
ls * | cat -n | head -100 | xargs -0 cp -t ~/foo/bar
```

The command reproduces a list of files on the screen and returns the warning `File name too long`.

I have tried also with `-exec cp -t` and its returns the message `-bash: -exec: command not found`.

Edit:
My filenames contain years (e.g. 1989a, 1989b,1991a, 1992c) so I would like to select all files published before a certain year (e.g. 1993).

Comment: `xargs -0` means that `xargs` wants the arguments to be separated by a null byte (instead of a space). Since no null bytes appear in the stream, `xargs` understands there's only one argument, and it passes the whole output of `head -100` as a single argument to `cp -t ~/foo/bar`. That's not what you want at all. Your command is really broken, and doesn't even express what you want to do. (Actually, why did you even use `cat -n`?)

Comment: Well, I added numbers to be able to select all files preceding a file on a line X.  So would only `xargs` without `-0` pass the output as individual arguments to `cp -t ~/foo/bar` ?

Comment: Yes, without `-0`, `xargs` will pass all _words_ as arguments to `cp`, but these words will also include the line numbers you added with `cat -n`, and it'll be very messy. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would result in 100 invocations of `cp` but you could just use a loop:

```
count=0; for i in *; do cp "$i" ~/foo/bar; ((++count == 100)) && break; done
```

Another way you could do this would be to use an array:

```
files=( * )
cp "${files[@]:0:100}" ~/foo/bar
```

The glob `*` expands to fill the array with the list of files in the current directory. The first 100 elements of the array are then copied.

Comment: This almost does the job. But, filenames contain years (e.g. 1989a, 1989b,1991a, 1992c) and I added line number simply to count and select first n files which correspond to those published for example before 1993. I'm not sure whether this is clear.

Comment: You should update your question to explain what you mean, then I'll change my answer.

Comment: I will. This second option you proposed answers my question actually.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you don't have too many files (so as to not exceed the maximum number of arguments and maximum buffer length of arguments allowed arguments on your machine), you can use something like:

```
shopt -s nullglob
cp -t ~/foo/bar {1970..1993}*
```

to copy all files that have a name starting with a number that lies between 1970 to 1993 (inclusive). Note that this will also copy a file named `197444`, if any, and also will try to copy directories that have a matching name (you'll get a warning that it's omitting it, unless you pass the `-r` flag too).

See:

- [Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion),
- [Filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion).

Comment: This is also good but I don't know if it would work if I want to select for example document preceding `1993e` without including that particular document. It seems from above that it is not possible to specify a range that would include say documents from `1993a` to `1993d`.

Comment: @user3635159: `1993{a..d}` would select `1993a`, `1993b`, `1993c` and `1993d`.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel it will look like this:

```
ls | head -100 | parallel -X cp {} ~/foo/bar
```